# Run multi scripts in a folder with cron

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I'm working with many scripts. So I do add/remove scripts with "`crontab -e`" so many times. I tried to make an "Available/Enabled" structure for these.

Example: 
This is my structure's tree:

```
# all scripts
scripts/available/1.sh
scripts/available/2.sh
scripts/available/3.sh

# enabled scripts 
scripts/enabled/1.sh -> scripts/available/1.sh
scripts/enabled/2.sh -> scripts/available/2.sh
```

Then I add this line to "`crontab -e`":

```
* * * * * /home/user/scripts/enabled/* &> /dev/null
```

This is the output of `sudo systemctl status cron.service` :

```
     CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
             ├─17763 /bin/bash /home/user/scripts/enabled/1.sh /home/user/scripts/enabled/2.sh
```

Finally: 
1.sh is working every minute, but 2.sh is not working.

I want to run scripts from only cron. What can I do for this, if I do not want to make a script for "run scripts in a directory" with another script,?

<sub>Also do you know any Telegram group for active "GNU/Linux System Administrators"?</sub>

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is it okay now ? @Algins

Comment: You can approve [my edit.](https://askubuntu.com/suggested-edits/174342)

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively you may use `run-parts` :

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/run-parts --regex='.+' /home/user/scripts/enabled
```

Parameter `--regex='.+'` allows any filenames.
Details: `man run-parts`.

Comment: Not worked for me.

Comment: run-parts by default do not accept a dot in filename. Rename `1.sh` to `1` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, its worked !

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
for script in /home/user/scripts/enabled/*; do $script &>/dev/null; done
```

Answer (score 4):

When you specify

```
/home/user/scripts/enabled/*
```

cron sees

```
/home/user/scripts/enabled/script1.sh /home/user/scripts/enabled/script2.sh ...
```

Thus, you are executing `script1.sh` with as arguments the pathnames of the other scripts in that directory. Your script1 does not read arguments: so it runs and it runs fine.

Instead, have `cron` run a script e expression to "not sure if cron works with wildcards the way you think"that, in turn, runs all scripts in the `enabled` directory. You can do that with a `for` ... `do` loop.

Comment: @terdon correct, of course. I changed this